# Error handling with C-string input using get() and getline()

Tags: c++, beginner, strings, error-handling, io

I've just learned the basics of c-strings and how to read line oriented input. I noticed that fail bits are set for each function. However, not every problem sends a fail bit, so I thought this would be a good exercise to try and target two user input errors:

1. The user enters no input
2. The user enters more input than the allocated number of elements

```
/*Simple Error handle using get() and getline() 
 *with too much input or no input on c-style strings
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    const int size = 10;

    std::cout << "Please enter your name and hit enter. Then have your friend do the same\n\n";

    //Using get()
    std::cout << "Your name: ";
    char name1[size];


    while (!std::cin.get(name1, size) || std::cin.get() != '\n') {
        if (!std::cin) {
            std::cout << "No input\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Name entered was too large for allocated memory...\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Try again: ";
    }

    //using getline()
    std::cout << "Your friends name: ";
    char name2[size];

    while (!std::cin.getline(name2, size) || name2[0] == NULL) {
        if(name2[0] == NULL){
            std::cout << "No input\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Name entered was too large for allocated memory...\n";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        std::cout << "Try Again: ";
    }

    std::cout << "\nNAME1: " << name1 << " NAME2: " << name2 << "\n";

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C style strings and `istream` don't go well with each other. I'm afraid you probably spent your time for nothing. C style char arrays are effective in solving some problems, but getting user input is the worst case scenario for them.

Comment: Yea, I agree, input into objects of type string is incredibly smooth and generally more ideal, c-strings lack the simplicity string objects do. However this was simply an exercise to do just a little bit of error handling on the c-string input!

Comment: @Incomputable Thank you though for pointing that out in the case I didn't know it!

Comment: You're welcome. `iostream`s are generally rarely used in C++. Usually people read from sockets, and libraries have dedicated API for reading only certain amount of information from it. I believe that writing good generic data structures and writing algorithms (generic or not) would be the best route of learning C++. Those probably cover most parts of C++ as well, at least most used ones.

Answer (score 2):

Writing all the code in a single huge `main()` is not only hard to read, but also a poor use of your skills.  Write a re-usable function to prompt and read input from a supplied `std::istream&`.  That will make it easier to test using a `std::istringstream`, too.

`name2[0] == NULL` looks like a pointer comparison.  You probably want to compare against `'\0'` so that it's clear we're dealing with *characters*.

Both loops cycle indefinitely when we reach end of input stream.  We probably should abort if `std::cin.eof()`.

The final `std::cin.get()` seems pointless, as we just discard the result.

`return 0;` can be omitted - just reaching the end of `main()` is equivalent.